# Error in ssh-rsa key when run a ansible playbook

Tags: ssh, ansible, key, paramiko

I have the following playbook:

```
---
- name: Get Nokia Info
  hosts: LAB9ERIP008
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: run show version command
      sros_command:
        commands: show version
      register: config

    - name: create backup of configuration
      copy:
        content: "{{config.stdout[0]}}"
        dest: "/home/dafe/scripts/ansible/backups/show_version_{{inventory_hostname}}.txt"
```

And when I run the playbook, give me the following error:

```
[dafe@CETPMGIP001 ansible]$ ansible-playbook nokia.yml -i myhostsfile 

PLAY [Get Cisco Info] **************************************************************************************************************

TASK [run show version command] ****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [LAB9ERIP008]: FAILED! => {"msg": "paramiko: The authenticity of host '10.150.16.129' can't be established.\nThe ssh-rsa key fingerprint is fca0d4eb97414dc5b5a13fa552e5dd69."}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/dafe/scripts/ansible/nokia.retry

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************
LAB9ERIP008                : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I tried to put in myhostsfile the var:

```
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/dafe/.ssh/known_hosts
```

But continues to give, the same error.

If I do ssh manually to the host and add the key:

```
[dafe@CETPMGIP001 ansible]$ ssh dafernandes@10.150.16.129
The authenticity of host '10.150.16.129 (10.150.16.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:0YQYfLnRCQDZzpZ1+8ekW/Gks6mTxpI4xA56siaQUsM.
RSA key fingerprint is MD5:fc:a0:d4:eb:97:41:4d:c5:b5:a1:3f:a5:52:e5:dd:69.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.150.16.129' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
TiMOS-C-16.0.R6 cpm/hops64 Nokia 7750 SR Copyright (c) 2000-2019 Nokia.
All rights reserved. All use subject to applicable license agreements.
Built on Wed Feb 27 14:42:05 PST 2019 by builder in /builds/c/160B/R6/panos/main

dafernandes@10.150.16.129's password:
```

And then run the playbook does not make the mistake anymore:

```
[dafe@CETPMGIP001 ansible]$ ansible-playbook nokia.yml -i myhostsfile 

PLAY [Get Cisco Info] **************************************************************************************************************

TASK [run show version command] ****************************************************************************************************
ok: [LAB9ERIP008]

TASK [create backup of configuration] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [LAB9ERIP008]

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************
LAB9ERIP008                : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks.

David

Comment: The data is not consistent. You claim to have playbook "**Get Nokia Info**", but report output "**PLAY [Get Cisco Info]**".

Comment: Something else is odd here: Ansible doesn't use Paramiko by default these days. You're either working with a very old version of Ansible or you've got an odd configuration.

Comment: @larsks Hi, I have the ansible 2.7.10 version

Comment: @Vladimir Botka. Well observed, but in the meantime he had copied the playbook. But the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `[defaults]` section of your [ansible.cfg](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-configuration-settings) file try setting the key `host_key_checking = false`.

This is obviously not as secure.

Being that SSH is the primary mechanism Ansible uses to communicate with target hosts, it is important that SSH is configured properly in your environment *before* attempting to execute Ansible playbooks.

The underlying problem in this case is likely that the SSH key associated with the SSH host you are trying to connect to has changed and no longer matches what is in ~/.ssh/known-hosts. More information about what SSH host keys are for can be found [here](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/host-key).

Comment: I removed the key from /.ssh/known_hosts and change the the entry host_key_checking to False and worked. Thanks.